# I cannot build webpack prod in jhipster

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, jhipster

I have a problem when build production with jhipster. Throw error when run webpack prod.

This is error:

```
[INFO] /var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/npm: line 37: 13802 Killed                  "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 137
[INFO] npm ERR! kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
[INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 137
[INFO] npm ERR! 
[INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
[INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[INFO] 
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T13_29_25_688Z-debug.log
[INFO] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[INFO] npm ERR! errno 137
[INFO] npm ERR! kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod: `npm run cleanup && npm run webpack:prod:main && npm run clean-www`
[INFO] npm ERR! Exit status 137
[INFO] npm ERR! 
[INFO] npm ERR! Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod script.
[INFO] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[INFO] 
[INFO] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[INFO] npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-19T13_29_25_928Z-debug.log
```

This is log debug:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node',
1 verbose cli   '/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'webpack:prod:main'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.13.1
4 verbose run-script [
4 verbose run-script   'prewebpack:prod:main',
4 verbose run-script   'webpack:prod:main',
4 verbose run-script   'postwebpack:prod:main'
4 verbose run-script ]
5 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~prewebpack:prod:main: kmaclassroom@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: kmaclassroom@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: PATH: /var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node_modules/.bin:/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node_modules/.bin:/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.252.b09-2.el7_8.x86_64:
9 verbose lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: CWD: /var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com
10 silly lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: Args: [
10 silly lifecycle   '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile'
10 silly lifecycle ]
11 silly lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: Returned: code: 137  signal: null
12 info lifecycle kmaclassroom@0.0.0~webpack:prod:main: Failed to exec webpack:prod:main script
13 verbose stack Error: kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
13 verbose stack Exit status 137
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid kmaclassroom@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com
16 verbose Linux 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64
17 verbose argv "/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node" "/var/www/html/kmaclassroom.com/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "run" "webpack:prod:main"
18 verbose node v12.13.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 137
22 error kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main: `npm run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --profile`
22 error Exit status 137
23 error Failed at the kmaclassroom@0.0.0 webpack:prod:main script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 137, true ]
```

Can you help me ! Thanks !

Comment: A prod build requires more memory than a dev build, and this increases when you add many entities. Have you tried to increase memory in package.json? This is why it is a good practice to run prod builds from first day of your  project usually in continuous integration.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I try change in package.json: 
`
"webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    
"webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
`
I run again through old error.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou What is the solution to this problem? Can you help me ?

Comment: If you doubled max_old_space_size to 8GB and the build still fails with error 137 then I have no other suggestions than to increase even more. Of course I assume that you are in 64 bits (both OS and node), right? How many entities do you have?

Comment: I have two entities. I run in centos 7 (RAM 4GB).

Comment: 4 GB is not enough to run a prod build, that's what you allocated for node to run! Even for dev, it's far from being enough when you run webpack dev server, spring boot server, IDE, Chrome, etc

Comment: Yes. Is there a solution to this problem without a server upgrade? Or the upgrade is required

Comment: Not to my knowledge. But just to be sure, why are you talking about a server? You mean for continuous integration? Just wanted to clarify that it's not a server for running the app, only for building it. Otherwise your dev PC could be enough.

Comment: I know. Howerver,  i want build project to web server and public domain.

Comment: Ah. I mean, I want to deploy my project in web server and can access it via domain but now I can't run prod.

Comment: You don't have to build your app on your deployment server. Build it on your development PC that has more power and memory (hopefully) , then deploy it to your production server. Production server just needs java installed (no nodejs, no maven), you upload your executable jar which includes bundled frontend and that's all. Of course you also need a database but you can have it on same server for small apps.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thank you. I try build in my dev PC with prod then another error appear. This is log error debug: [error-log].https://pastebin.com/xd15m6uX Can you see help me ! I did not understand what was going on.

Comment: I don't understand either because I don't know enough details : how you started the build (maven, gradle, npm?), OS seems to be Darwin, dev build works? Please open a new question, this one is no longer relevant.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Have nice a day !